# Print out NID of entity reference

Tags: 7, entities

I have a custom field that is an entity reference, when using

> print render($content['field_call_to_action_1']);

in a content type template it prints out the title *Call to Action 1*, and the Title of the content that the entity reference is linked too.

How can I just get it to print out the NID instead?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$content is to be rendered and obeys what you have set in node(other other entity) type's Display Settings (Administer > Structure >Content Types).

What you should use is, $node object.

```
<pre>
<?php
print_r($node);
?>
</pre>
```

Now you will see a nicely formatted information of $node object which also has the NID you want.

You will be able to access it with this:

```
$node->field_call_to_action_1['und'][0]['target_id']
```

Quick hint:If you are trying to build a URL link from this value, have a look at url() and l() functions!

Comment: I don't know is it just my case, but it didn't worked for me. I used 'target_id' instead of 'nid' and worked fine.